# SQL Server procedure to Oracle procedure without using tool

Tags: sql-server, oracle, plsql

Can someone help and guide me to convert the below SQL Server procedure to an Oracle procedure?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proc1 AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @table1 TABLE (currency_id INT, amt_total_exp DECIMAL(18,4));
    DECLARE @table2 TABLE (contract_id INT);

    INSERT INTO @table2
        EXEC someProcedure 28, '28-11-2020';

    INSERT INTO @table1
        SELECT currency_id, SUM(amount_direct_exposure)
        FROM someTable d
        INNER JOIN @table2 c ON d.contract_id = c.contract_id   
        GROUP BY currency_id;

    SELECT * FROM @table1
END

SomeProcedure will provide result as follows

 contract_id
-------------
1
2
3
4
5
```

The date param in Someprocedure is used to list the contract_id those were active till that date for a particular party

The SomeProcedure has nothing to do with @table1. The @table1 is used to hold the result of Someprocedure So that it can be used while inserting in @table2.

The Proc1 is working fine in SQL server. I have tested it

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you posted sample data as well as what is `someprocedure` supposed to do. I *guess* it inserts those values into `table2`, but - what is date doing here? No idea, so I omit it.

I'd suggest a procedure which accepts (at least one) parameter: `par_contract_id`. It makes the procedure *reusable*; with hardcoded values, you can use it only once (i.e. with that hardcoded set of values).

Something like this:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure proc1 (par_contract_id in number) as
  2  begin
  3    insert into table1 (currency_id, amt_total_exp)
  4      select s.currency_id,
  5             sum(s.amount_direct_exposure)
  6      from sometable s
  7      where s.contract_id = par_contract_id
  8      group by s.currency_id;
  9  end;
 10  /

Procedure created.
```

Suppose that `sometable` looks like this:

```
SQL> select * from sometable;

CONTRACT_ID AMOUNT_DIRECT_EXPOSURE CURRENCY_ID
----------- ---------------------- -----------
          1                    100         225
          1                    500         225
          2                    200         382
```

Passing `contract_id = 1` to the procedure, it should sum `100 + 500` and insert a row into `table1`:

```
SQL> begin
  2    proc1(1);
  3  end;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from table1;

CURRENCY_ID AMT_TOTAL_EXP
----------- -------------
        225           600

SQL>
```

Comment: SomeProcedure will provide a list of active contract_id associated with a party_id Essentially the data will be    
 
contract_id
------------------
       1
       2
       3

The date field in some procedure is to list active contract till that date.

Comment: OK; so, if you have to populate that "additional" table in the "someProcedure", do it. Then join "additional" table with "sometable".

Comment: I would try to rephrase the word. In proc1 I want to call someProcedure which give a list of integer value. This integer value I want to insert in a temporary table. How do I achieve it

Comment: Use INSERT INTO "temporary table" statement In someProcedure.

Comment: I am not supposed to change SomeProcedure. the idea is to use the result of some procedure in proc1

Comment: I have difficulties in understanding what you really have. SomeProcedure "gives list of integer value". What is that? What "list"? How? Though, saying that you want to do something with a "temporary table": note that Oracle isn't *fan* of temporary tables. They are frequently used in MS SQL Server, but Oracle usually don't need those, as it is quite well in using results of inline views, subqueries, CTEs and stuff.

Answer (score -1):

You can refer to the following

--1./ Create two table temporary global -------

```
create global temporary table table1 (currency_id number, amt_total_exp number);
on commit delete rows;

create global temporary table table2 (contract_id number);
on commit delete rows;
```

--2./ Create Produre ----------

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proc1 AS
    V_contract_id number;
BEGIN

    V_contract_id := someProcedure(28, '28-11-2020');

    INSERT INTO table2
    (
        contract_id
    )
    VALUE 
    (
        V_contract_id
    );

    INSERT INTO table1
    SELECT currency_id, SUM(amount_direct_exposure)
    FROM 
    someTable d
    table2 c  
    WHERE 1=1 AND d.contract_id = c.contract_id  
    GROUP BY currency_id;

    --Output log --------------------------------
    FOR I IN (SELECT * FROM table1)
    LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('currency_id: ' || I.currency_id);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('amt_total_exp: ' || I.amt_total_exp);
    END LOOP;

    COMMIT;
END;
```

Comment: someProcedure(28, '28-11-2020'); will return multiple rows. Does your solution work in that scenario?

Comment: @Hung Le - much better if you use ANSI standard JOIN syntax for your joins: 'SELECT ... FROM someTable d join table2 c  on d.contract_id = c.contract_id'